# Custom hh:mm:ss to decimal seconds

Tags: excel, time, format

I have some time data that has been imported into excel.  For example, the cell will have:

```
10:01:55 AM
```

The format is Custom as `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.

I want to convert this into seconds so I can run some calculations. I've tried playing with the format to no avail.

I've also tried this but it results in 0.

```
= HOUR(A1)*3600 + MINUTE(A1)*60 + SECOND(A1)
```

Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems correct to me, though there might be a more direct way to do the conversion.  I think your confusion is arising because the cell into which you entered the formula is *still* formatted as `hh:mm:ss AM/PM`.  If you change the formatting of the cell to `Number` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> then select "Number"), then you get the output you want:

[image]

**Update:**

Based on the detective work from @micuzzo, an alternative to the lengthy formula is to simple use:

```
A1 * 86400
```

where `86400` is the number of seconds in a 24 hour day.

Comment: No, you're not a fool, because you actually did the conversion correctly.  You simply overlooked a small configuration issue which was a bit obfuscated.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Excel and I'd forgotten that inserting a new column keeps the formatting from the adjacent left column. With that being said, I more direct solution would also be interesting if it is possible.

Comment: I don't think you can use `CONVERT()` here because cell `A1` does not contain hours or minutes, it contains a timestamp.  Most of the material I found online use your formula, although there do appear to be some custom add-ons that can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! In case anyone is reading, what can work is simply multiplying by 86400 (seconds in a day) if the times aren't greater than 24.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the format of the cell to get what you wanted.  You can right click on the cell and select Format cell then choose General.

Jim